# How to increase priority of my custom CSS?

Tags: 8, theming

I have this View:
[image]
The empty rows have a `distrib0` class that should make the background red.
For that I have a custom CSS (amap.css) with `tr.distrib0 {BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FF0000;}` in it.
I have this `amap.libraries.yml` containing

```
amap:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/amap.css: {}
  js:
      js/amap.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/drupalSettings
```

and finally, I attach the CSS with

```
function amap_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view) {
  if($view->id() == 'calendrier_des_distributions' && $view->current_display == 'page_1') {
    $view->element['#attached']['library'][] = 'amap/amap';
  }
}
```

As you can see in the screen capture, my CSS is there but after `color.css` which is part of the current theme.
And of course my background is not red!
What can I do (besides adding `tr.distrib0 in tr.distrib0` to `color.css`which I'd prefer to avoid)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added wrong CSS here. Background color will not works with tr tag because we have style of td over tr tag.
Please correct with this code

```
tr.distrib0 td {
 background-color:#FF0000 !important;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't change anything. My CSS code is still after `color.css`, as you can see [here](https://imgur.com/a/V7oTsJp)

Comment: I have updated code. Please check it now.

Comment: Have you cleared website cache after saving css file ?

Comment: Enjoy! In Drupal whenever you'll do any changes in files, you must have to clear cache.